# simple method aliasing in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code

```
var object = Ember.Object.create({
  foo: Ember.computed.alias('bar'),
  bar: function(){
    console.log('bar');
  }
});

object.foo();
```

It raises

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ember.computed.alias` is for computed properties only. Instead, use the [aliasMethod](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_aliasMethod) computed function.

```
var object = Ember.Object.create({
    foo: Ember.aliasMethod('bar'),
    bar: function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
});

object.foo();
```

EDIT: I previously thought you could do something like `o.get('foo')()` to call the method using `Ember.computed.alias`, but that turns out to not be the case. Not 100% sure why, but it wouldn't work in the JSBin I set up. Either way, `aliasMethod` does work.